# How to change Jupyter launch from file to URL?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I installed Python 3.7 from Windows Store, it runs perfectly. I successfully installed Jupyter and other packages with `pip` from cmd.

The thing is when I run Jupyter (`python -m notebook`) it says

[image: python message]

and automaticaly opens the browser with an ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND page. Opening the notebook by copy-pasting the URLs works just as expected, so how can I tell Jupyter to run by default the URL instead of the file?

Comment: What happens when you just run `jupyter notebook` ?

Comment: "jupyter" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: well if `jupyter` is not an internal command then it was not successfully installed. Have you tried to uninstall python and re-install it via anaconda ?

Comment: When I do `pip install jupyter` it says is correctly installed. Also it runs ok by using the URL. I suspect that the HTML file can't be written because of permissions, the same reason I can't install Python via Anaconda or its own installer.

Answer (score 4):

At my end, the file does not open either due to security settings of Chromium (ERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

There's a config parameter which controls how the browser gets access to jupyter: `NotebookApp.use_redirect_fileBool` (cf. jupyter [docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)).

In order to change this, create a config by `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and edit the config file: uncomment and replace the value of line `#c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = True` by `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`. On next start of jupyter, the browser is started using the http URL instead of the file.

HTH

Comment: Sounds pretty accurate, but I completely changed my system so I can't tell if this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works (UBUNDU). You just have to bare in mind a few thinks:

1st: If you use jupyter notebook you need to craete this file  `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and look for the line `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = True` .
If you use jupyter-lab (as I do) you need to use this command `jupyter-lab --generate-config` . Also, in jupyter-lab you need to find this line `c.ServerApp.use_redirect_file = True` . In both cases this `True` needs to become `False` .

PS. I wanted to add it as a comment but I was not able to do so due to reputation or something.

2nd: It is given in the previous answer but its easy to be missed: you need to uncomment the line (remove the "#" at the start of the line)

Comment: Hope somebody could test this and tell us if it works.